# What is the "honey stick" called?

Tags: utensils

I often see this utensil used in pictures of honey:

[image: Honey stick]

I've never seen this stick-like utensil used in other contexts, just for honey. But what is this "honey stick" called exactly? And is it used only for honey or for other things?

Comment: It's also used for [stroop](http://www.thedutchtable.com/2011/12/appelstroop.html) ... but that's even harder to find than the sticks in the U.S.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most common term is "[honey dipper](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/honey_dipper)".

It goes by several different names, though... largely because people usually [can't remember](http://www.seriouseats.com/2007/06/does-anyone-use-the-honey-thin.html) what it's *actually* called:

> Steven of The Sneeze takes a look at the widespread use of "the honey thing"—also known as a honey dipper, honey wand, or honey drizzler—on cereal boxes despite that few people seem to actually use these honey things

So, "honey stick" would probably get people to think of this tool, too.

For more information see the related question:

- [How to use a honey dipper?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32241/how-to-use-a-honey-dipper)

Comment: "Honey **drizzler**" is what I've always known it as.

Comment: "The honey thing, you know like the bee on the cereal box uses" for me.